# how to verify if the field of select2 is blank or not

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a Python/Django project where I'm trying to add 'select2' to facilitate user search from a list of banks:

```
    class BuyerNaturalPersonBankAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
select_bank = MajorBankList(
    label='Banco',
    required=False,
    )

class Meta:
    model = BuyerBankAccount
    fields = (
        'name',
        'cpf',
        'cnpj',
        'select_bank',
        'bank',
        'bank_code',
        'agency',
        'account',
        'account_type',
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bank'].required = False
    self.fields['bank_code'].required = False
    self.fields['bank'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['bank_code'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank_code',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['select_bank'].widget = forms.Select(
        choices=self.fields['select_bank'].choices,
        attrs={
            'v-model': 'selectedBank',
            '@change': 'onBankChange',
            'data-select2-enabled': True,
        }
    )
```

In my base.html, i have added the select2:

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-select2-enabled]').select2({
                    closeOnSelect: true,
                    theme: "bootstrap"
                });
            });
            </script>
```

In HTML code, I implement a check to disable the "bank" and "bank_code" fields when the user selects a "select_bank:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        street: '',
        district: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        country: '',
        cpf: '',
        name: '',
        mother_name: '',
        father_name: '',
        nationality: '',
        selectedBank: '',
        bank: '',
        bank_code: '',
        bankAccountOwnerName: '',
        bankAccountCPF: '',
        birth_date: '',
        public_person: false,
        isLoading: false,
        isPostalCodeFound: true,
        isCPFFound: true,
        display_form_address: false,
        display_form_bank: false,
        hasError: '{{ error }}',
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        this.bank = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-bank').value
        this.bank_code= this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-bank_code').value
        this.postal_code = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-postal_code').value
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-select2-enabled]').select2({
                closeOnSelect: true,
                theme: "bootstrap"
            });
        });
```

And I perform this check to disable the field:

```
            computed: {
            isBankDisabled: function() {
                return this.selectedBank !== '';
            }
        },
```

When I check if return this.selectedBank === '', the value becomes true regardless of whether I fill in something in the select_bank field or not. Even if I leave the field blank or fill it in, the values of bank and bank_code are always disabled. In reality, according to the logic I modified, they should only be disabled when the value is blank.

If I remove the select2, the logic starts working normally again:

```
        self.fields['select_bank'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'selectedBank',
            '@change': 'onBankChange',
            'data-select2-enabled': False,
```

Comment: the question is hard to understand.. it's not clear how to dig down the issue since there's no correlation between the function you showed, the `selectedBank` property that you didn't show anywhere and the select element. Is `selectedBank` supposed to be the id of the select element? are you retrieving the element like that? or its value?

Comment: The code looks like Vue, not jQuery. Are you trying to use a jQuery component in a vue app? [Vue dev tools](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) might be able to help, it lets you inspect the data and components more easily.

Comment: the select2 is jquery, im trying use a jquery component in vue.app

Comment: You might want to add the Vue tag to the question then. Have you tried the Vue developer tools I linked above? Post the relevant code in your question, so the selectedBank in data, the template output, the select2 initialization - anything that can help. You may have an error or a typo anywhere. The vue dev-tools show you the components and their data, I find it the easiest way to see.

Comment: I have edited with de 'complete' code.

Comment: See [data() in Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data) - data is supposed to be a function that returns an object, not just an object directly. Example from the docs: `data() { return { a: 1 } }`.

Comment: Peter, still returning blank value

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const submit = $('#submit');
  submit.click(function(){
    var $select = $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    var selectedValue = $select.val();
            console.log(selectedValue);
    if (selectedValue === null || selectedValue.length === 0) {
        console.log('Input is blank');
    } else {
        console.log('Input is not blank');
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>
  
  <title>Select 2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  </select>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```